# How do I connect to Hive from spark using Scala on IntelliJ?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, hive

I am new to hive and spark and am trying to figure out a way to access tables in hive to manipulate and access the data. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

in spark < 2.0

```
 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

 val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
 val myDataFrame = sqlContext.sql("select * from mydb.mytable")
```

in later versions of spark, use SparkSession:

> SparkSession is now the new entry point of Spark that replaces the old
>   SQLContext and HiveContext. Note that the old SQLContext and
>   HiveContext are kept for backward compatibility. A new catalog
>   interface is accessible from SparkSession - existing API on databases
>   and tables access such as listTables, createExternalTable,
>   dropTempView, cacheTable are moved here.
>   -- from the docs

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark Hive Example")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
 val myDataFrame = spark.sql("select * from mydb.mytable")
```

Comment: Does `...warehouse.dir` refer to a location from the point of view of the driver program (e.g. spark-shell) or that of the worker nodes?  My worker can see a table's file via `hdfs` from `hdfs://namenodeHA/apps/hive/warehouse/some_db.db/some_table` , but my driver cannot.  How should I specify the location?

Comment: Is your driver running within the managed cluster or outside of it? it seems to be outside of it when your workers can see the metastore but your driver can't

Comment: Outside. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your hive server resides on remote cluster you can refer pulling data over jdbc connection like:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList

case class TempTable (
  column1: String,
  column2: String
)

val conn: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
val res: ResultSet = conn.createStatement
                   .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name")
val fetchedRes = MutableList[TempTable]()
while(res.next()) {
  var rec = TempTable(res.getString("column1"), 
     res.getString("column2"))
  fetchedRes += rec
}
conn.close()
val resultRDD = sc.parallelize(fetchedRes)
resultRDD.cache()
```

Comment: Do note that this approach is far from ideal to run production workloads, as all data needs to first go through the driver before it can be send to the worker nodes. However if you are just doing some development, it can be helpful.

Comment: @Havnar author is novice and looking for advice how to access and manipulate data  most probably in local machine using IDE.